# Excel If function can't show cell format

Tags: microsoft-excel

**What should I do if I want the data in C9 to be same as B9 after using IF function?**

For cell B9, the format is `##.00"m`, showing `3.30m`

For cell C9, the formula is `=IF($B$9<6,$B$9&" ceiling height",$B$9&" ceiling height")`
and `3.3 ceiling height` is shown.

If I want it to be `3.30m ceiling height`

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
=IF($B$9<6,TEXT($B$9,"##.00")&"m"&" ceiling height",$B$9&" ceiling height")
```

Comment: Since, regardless of the result of comparing cell B9 with the number 6, both values - for both True and False - are the same, it would be possible to limit ourselves to simple `=TEXT($B$9,"##.00") &"m ceiling height"`